# hibernate select distinct values order by one value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I want to get distinct values from my db.
I have 10 fields in this db, and when i try to use such query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (IMIE)FROM `przychodzace`
```

I get 26 results, but hibernate returns me just 17...
Here is list function:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PrzychodzaceModel.class);
    if (i == 0) {
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("imie")));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("imie"));
    }
    list = criteria.list();
    System.out.println(list.size() + "size");
    return list;
```

Have anyone idea how to do it properly, i am trying to correct it for long time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about what is in the IMIE column. What are the 26 values from sql and the 17 from hibernate that are returned? Also hibernate could be joining your query with another table limiting your results. You might look at the raw SQL output and see what the query is.

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative to your problem would be to use a DAO class with a List method, eg:

```
public List listMenu() {
    String hql = "FROM Menu";
    org.hibernate.Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setFirstResult(0);
    query.setMaxResults(5);
    List results = query.list();
    return results;
}
```